# How can I create a celsius to fahrenheit conversion table with php?

Tags: php, converters

As part of my computer science homwork I need to create a table with php that converts a celsius value to fahrenheit. From 0 to 50. The attached image shows the desired result. Can anyone give me a hint on how to go about it or provide me with the code?
Thank you very much in advance.

[image: Celsius to fahrenheit php conversion table]

Comment: You go look up the formula, you go read up on how a simple `for` loops works … and you are basically there already.

Comment: what have you tried thus far?

Comment: @treyBake I've tried a while loop, but it didn't work...

Comment: Then please show your code and tell us how it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer:

```
<?php

$celsius = 0;

while ($celsius <= 50) {

    $fahrenheit = $celsius * 1.8 + 5;

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$celsius&deg</td>";
    echo "<td>$fahrenheit&deg</td>";

    $celsius = $celsius + 5;
}

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

have fun at your classes mate ^_^

```
<?php
function getFahrenheit(int $celsius)
{
    return ($celsius * 9/5) + 32;
}

echo "<table><tr><th>Celcius</th><th>Fahrenheit<th></tr>";
for($celcius = 0; $celcius <= 50; $celcius+=5) {
    echo sprintf("<tr><td>%d</td><td>%d</td></tr>", $celcius, getFahrenheit($celcius));
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: this doesn't explain anything, it's much better to explain your answers so OP has an understanding ...

Comment: @myxaxa Unfortunately the code doesn't work, but thanks

Comment: what version of php do tou use?:) to check version type: php -v in console.

Comment: @myxaxa CLI and phpinfo() function may return different php versions. The best way to see what PHP version the site uses, is adding a info.php in the site root with the code: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and going to `site.local/info.php` to see the version